# PHP higher version installed and used, however, lower version vulnerabilities found

Tags: php, linux, apache, security, redhat

Using a website, apache php configuration on red hat 5.5.
[root@server ~]# php -version

```
PHP 5.5.25 (cli) (built: Jun 12 2016 12:37:38)

Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group

Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

[root@server ~]# httpd -version

Server version: Apache/2.2.3

Server built:   Mar  4 2010 09:57:54
```

I have a website hosted which is published on both 80 and 443.
I have received a full set of vulnerabilities looking like below -

Vulnerability - PHP Vulnerability: CVE-2007-1824
Recommended_Action - Upgrade to PHP version 5.2.1
Download and apply the upgrade from:

> http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.2.1.tar.gz

Vulnerability - 
PHP Fixed possible invalid read in glob() win32 implementation
PHP Fixed iconv_*() functions to limit argument sizes (CVE-2007-4840)

Recommended action - 
Upgrade to PHP version 5.2.4

Download and apply the upgrade from:

> http :// museum.php.net/php5/php-5.2.4.tar.gz

Upgrade to PHP version 5.2.5Download and apply the upgrade from:

> http :// museum.php.net/php5/php-5.2.5.tar.gz

What i fail to understand is from where is it detecting an old version of php. I dont have it installed on the server.

When i do a find php, this is what i get. I have installed v5.5.25 on my server.

```
[root@server ~]# find / -name php

/var/lib/php

/usr/bin/php

/usr/local/lib/php

/usr/local/bin/php

/usr/local/php

/usr/local/include/php

/usr/lib64/php

/appl/softwares/php-7.0.7/sapi/cli/php

/appl/softwares/php-5.5.25/sapi/cli/php

[root@server ~]#
```

Please help.

Comment: It is now solved. It was basically re why i'm seeing old version vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved.
It was a very basic problem with having 2 versions of php installed on the server.
php -v shows 5.5.25 and phpinfo() was showing the older version(5.1.6)

As the vulnerability report had been taken for my website, and apache was using 5.1.16, i was getting the older vulnerabilities.

This has been fixed by adding the correct libphp5.so in the LoadModule in httpd.conf.

A common error, however, a different issue to find the error.

Thank you.